# How to set char as labels on x axis? matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of characters e.g. `['a','a','b','b']`. When I plot them this way:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x_labels = ['a','a','b','b']
y = [0,1,2,3]

plt.plot(x_labels,y)
plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

However, I would like to have on x-axis: `a,a,b,b`, not just `a,b`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dummy integers to set the position of the points and label the respective ticks according to your `x_labels` array

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x_labels = ['a','a','b','b']
y = [0,1,2,3]

plt.plot(range(len(x_labels)),y)
plt.xticks(range(len(x_labels)), x_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x_labels = ['a','a','b','b']

# Create dummy x values, with a value for every label entry
x = np.r_[:len(x_labels)]
y = [0,1,2,3]

plt.scatter(x, y, color='r', marker='x')

# Change the xticks as desired
plt.xticks(x, x_labels)
plt.show()
```

This trick is to set the x-values as placeholder integers and then change their label to whatever you desire.

This gave me the following plot, which I think is what you desired:

[image]

Comment: Instead of grabbing the axis, you can use `plt.xticks(x, x_labels)`

Comment: You're right, thanks. Edited answer to reflect this